BindableProperty from a component doesn't pass the change to the calling page
I'm doing some tests with the components in .NET 8 MAUI. I'm testing an elementary component called NewContent1. This is the XAML of the page
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="MyComponent.NewContent1">
    <Entry Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</ContentView>

And then here is the code behind:
namespace MyComponent;

public partial class NewContent1 : ContentView
{
    public NewContent1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MyPropertyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(MyProperty),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(NewContent1),
        string.Empty);

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
    }
}

Simple. Now, in the MainPage, I add the component and this is the XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MyComponent.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:component="clr-namespace:MyComponent;assembly=MyComponent">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0" Spacing="25">
            <component:NewContent1 MyProperty="{Binding MyVariable}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding MyVariable}" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

and then this is the code behind
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private string _myVariable;
    public string MyVariable
    {
        get => _myVariable;
        set
        {
            _myVariable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyVariable));
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}

So, I expect that when a user types anything in the Entry the property MyProperty is updated (and this is working) but also the variable MyVariable in the MainPage is updated too but this is not working.
What did I miss?

From the BindableProperty doc, the defaultBindingMode is BindingMode.OneWay, which means the change of MyProperty would not bring about the change of  MyVariable.
Another question, the BindingContext of the ContentPage is itself as you set the BindingContext in the page's constructor. NewContent1 should have inherited the BindingContext from its parent (the page). But you also set the BindingContext = this; in the ContentView's constructor, which leads to MyProperty unable to bind to MyVariable.
Solution
For the BindableProperty, explicitly set the BindingMode in the Create method,
public static readonly BindableProperty MyPropertyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(MyProperty),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(NewContent1),
    string.Empty,
    BindingMode.TwoWay);

And when you set the BindingContext of the NewContent1, set Content.BindingContext = this; instead of BindingContext = this; in NewContent1 constructor,
public NewContent1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Content.BindingContext = this;
}

or you can also use x:reference expression if you want, such as
<ContentView    ...
         x:Name="this">

<Entry Text="{Binding MyProperty, Source={x:Reference this}}" />

Then no need to set the BindingContext in NewContent1 constructor,
public NewContent1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    //Content.BindingContext = this;   //remove 
}

Hope it helps!

Thank you for your answer, I thought TwoWay was the default. Plus, the mistake was I was using a variable that I haven't define in the MainPage.
